# How do I return a Promise with this custom type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, typescript-generics, return-type

What I can't figure how is how ParsedAuthorizationResponse is implemented and how I can set it's values differently. Eventually, I want to return a certain value/type as a promise.

I thought this would work but it doesn't

```
let PAR; 
if (status === 'COMPLETED') { 
PAR = new ParsedAuthorizationResponse('AUTHORIZED')
} else throw new Error('Authorization failed')

return Promise<PAR>;
}

//Also tried this but didn't work

type ParsedAuthorizationResponse PAR = 'AUTHORIZED';
return new Promise<PAR>;
```

Comment: Just `return PAR;` - no promises needed, you're in an `async function` already which does the wrapping already

Answer (score 5):

`ParsedAuthorizationResponse` isn't a *class* (which is why `new` doesn't work), it's a *type*. In this case, it's a bunch of different possible object shapes. Let's have a look

```
  export type ParsedAuthorizationResponse =
  | IAuthResponse<
      { processorTransactionId: string },
      'AUTHORIZED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'SETTLING' | 'SETTLED'
    >
  | IAuthResponse<{ declineReason: string }, 'DECLINED'>
  | IAuthResponse<{ errorMessage: string }, 'FAILED'>;
```

Right, this tells us that `ParsedAuthorizationResponse` is just a synonym for any one of three different parametrizations of `IAuthResponse`. Unfortunately, that doesn't tell us much until we know what `IAuthResponse` looks like. Which we do, fortunately:

```
type IAuthResponse<T, U extends TransactionStatus> = T & {
  transactionStatus: U;
};
```

OK, this gets more concrete. `TransactionStatus` is just a synonym for a couple of literal strings, and `T & { transactionStatus: U; }` is a *type conjunction*, meaning that the result is a type that is just like the type `T`, plus a field `transactionStatus` which is of type `U` (which with `U extends TransactionStatus` is constrained to be one or more of the strings we know as `TransactionStatus`).

So what does something like `IAuthResponse<{ errorMessage: string }, 'FAILED'>` mean? Well, looking at `IAuthResponse`, it expands to this:

```
{ errorMessage: string } & { transactionStatus: 'FAILED' }
```

which is the same as

```
{ errorMessage: string; transactionStatus: 'FAILED' }
```

Which means that `ParsedAuthorizationResponse` actually looks like this:

```
type ParsedAuthorizationResponse =
      | { processorTransactionId: string; transactionStatus: 'AUTHORIZED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'SETTLING' | 'SETTLED' }
      | { declineReason: string; transactionStatus: 'DECLINED' }
      | { errorMessage: string; transactionStatus: 'FAILED' }
```

So, creating an object conforming to `ParsedAuthorizationResponse` is really easy, it's just object literals:

- If it's failed, it's an object with `transactionStatus: 'FAILED'` and an arbitrary `errorMessage` string
- If it's declined, you have `transactionStatus: 'DECLINED'` and an arbitrary `declineMessage` string
- Else, it has `transactionStatus` set to one of `'AUTHORIZED'`, `'CANCELLED'`, `'SETTLING'`, or `'SETTLED'`, plus a  `processorTransactionId` which is a string that I assume you get along with the status of the transaction.

Your example would end up something like this:

```
  async authorize(
    request: RawAuthorizationRequest<ClientIDSecretCredentials, PayPalOrder>,
  ): Promise<ParsedAuthorizationResponse> {
      // The response needs to contain status and transaction ID
      const { status, processorTransactionId } = JSON.parse(await response) as { status: string; processorTransactionId: string; }
      switch (status) {
        case 'COMPLETE':
          return { transactionStatus: 'AUTHORIZED', processorTransactionId };
        case 'VOIDED':
          return { transactionStatus: 'CANCELLED', processorTransactionId };
        // TODO: Fill in more cases here...
        default: 
          // Unknown status, hopefully shouldn't happen, but for the sake of
          // argument, let's pretend that failing the transaction is a reasonable
          // thing to do here, just to show how to return an error message
          return { transactionStatus: 'FAILED', errorMessage: 'Unknown status: ' + status };
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the brilliant answer and taking the time to write it! It clears a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a promise type is very easy and is not different then returning a promise of a primitive.

Any value you return from an `async` function will be wrapped with a promise, so:

```
const returnsANumber = async (): Promise<number> => {
  return 42
}

type Foo = {
  foo: true
}

const returnsAFoo = async (): Promise<Foo> => {
  return {
    foo: true
  }
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUygVzpAggOWQWwEYJwwC8MAhhAJ5jAwAUAlAFwwAKcIOAlhAgDxhcBOAD4SYgN4AoGPCSowMACwAmKQF8pUqJQAOCGADEQIEjGmyAZiZZQ4yBBq2hIsRCjQR0x06QrVaRhZ2Th5+HzFiSRk5D0ULWRhrEFt7R1lNdSA)

In your case just return a `ParsedAuthorizationResponse`

Comment: Thank you! I understand the promises part now. Could you please help me figure out how to set the value for ParsedAuthorizationResponse? Because I can't seem to figure out how it's implemented and how I would set it to, say, 'AUTHORIZED' or 'DECLINED' or something like that and then return that type of it in my promise.

Comment: if I follow your code you should just return `PAR`

Answer (score 1):

First, as @thedude said, because your function is already `async` there is no need to return a Promise, whatever you return will be automatically turned into a Promise.

Now to answer: "How to return a `ParsedAuthorizationResponse`".

Starting with the (part of) defintion:

```js
export type ParsedAuthorizationResponse =
  | IAuthResponse<
      { processorTransactionId: string },
      'AUTHORIZED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'SETTLING' | 'SETTLED'
    >
```

(I'm only going to do this logic with one example of ParsedAuthorisationResponse in the hope you can do the rest)

This says that it's an `IAuthResponse<T, U>` where T is `{ processorTransactionId: string }` and U is `'AUTHORIZED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'SETTLING' | 'SETTLED'`

Slotting this *into* the defintion of IAuthResponse gives us

```js
type IAuthResponse<T, U extends TransactionStatus> = {
  processorTransactionId: string,
  transactionStatus: 'AUTHORIZED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'SETTLING' | 'SETTLED';
};
```

Meaning an example of `ParsedAuthorizationResponse` is

```js
{
  processorTransactionId: "any old string",
  transactionStatus: 'AUTHORIZED',
}
```

So to return it from your function use something like:

```js
async authorize(
    request: RawAuthorizationRequest<ClientIDSecretCredentials, PayPalOrder>,
  ):ParsedAuthorizationResponse {
      //just imagine I'm gonna get a response that has a value of status in it
      const { status } = JSON.parse(await response)
      
      return {
          processorTransactionId: status, // or whatever
          transactionStatus: 'AUTHORIZED',
      };
  }
```